# Can you replace cyclocross (or road bike) handlebars with mountain bike handlebars?

Tags: road-bike, mountain-bike, handlebars

My cyclocross handlebars are really irritating, please help.

Comment: Please edit your question to include details about why you want to switch, or what it is about your current setup is "irritating". The answer to "can I replace..." is almost always "Yes - with enough money" but whether or not it's a good idea depends highly on the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: The hard part, if you switch between "drop" handlebars and "flat" handlebars, is getting the shifters and break levers to work.  Generally the existing ones will not work very well in the new configuration, and often you will find it difficult to find replacement units that are "compatible" in terms of the amount of cable "pull" for a given action.

Comment: I'll add that the reason for "drop" bars "not working well" is often that they are too low or too far forward or both.  Replacing the stem with one with more rise and less forward extension will often make a world of difference.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Pesha. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site, and since you're asking [ask] will help also.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are talking about the handlebar. It is not an easy swap - you would need a new flat/riser bar, new shifters (to match the existing gears), new brake levers (to match the existing brakes), more than likely new cables and housing, plus some grips. Depending on the level of quality of the shifters...it could get very expensive. It could be more cost effective to sell that bike and buy a flat bar commuter.

If it is a comfort issue, there are things that you can do to make the bike fit you better...you don't say why it is irritating.

Good luck.